# How can I convert Bytes Array to String on Kotlin other than String()?

Tags: kotlin

```
[51, -42, 119, -85, -64, 126, 22, 127, -72, 72, 48, -66, -18, 45, 99, -119]
```

This is the BytesArray that I want to print in String.
When I searched on the internet, I found that

```
String(Bytes, Charsets.UTF_8)
```

would convert it to String.
However, I get �؉���Q�t, and doesn't seem to be converted in right way.
Why is it?

Comment: What do you expect the resulting string to be?

Comment: I want it to be String in English Alphabet and numbers

Comment: Here's a blog post by one of the founders of Stack Overflow: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Comment: Where do the bytes come from? How do you know that the bytes can be represented as English text? What encoding is it in?

Comment: Or maybe you want to encode it to hexadecimal or base 64? The question is unanswerable without more details.

Answer (score 1):

> I want it to be String in Alphabet characters and numbers

Firstly, you are specifying an array of signed bytes (indicated by negative numbers):

```kotlin
51, -42, 119, -85, -64, 126, 22, 127, -72, 72, 48, -66, -18, 45, 99, -119
```

Let's take a look at what this would hypothetically look like if it were unsigned ([I used this tool for the conversion](https://onlinetoolz.net/unsigned-signed)):

```kotlin
51, 214, 119, 171, 192, 126, 22, 127, 184, 72, 48, 190, 238, 45, 99, 137
```

Assuming by "Alphabet characters and numbers", you mean the English alphabet, then [asciitable](https://www.asciitable.com/) will help you identify each character's decimal value, but as a rough guide:

- "0"-"9" = 48-57
- "A"-"Z" = 65-90
- "a"-"z" = 97-122

Consider the following code sample:

```kotlin
/**
 * You can edit, run, and share this code. 
 * play.kotlinlang.org 
 */

fun main() {
    val bytes = byteArrayOf(51, -42, 119, -85, -64, 126, 22, 127, -72, 72, 48, -66, -18, 45, 99, -119)
    val string = bytes.toString(Charsets.US_ASCII)
    
    println(string)
}
```

As you can see, some of the values in the unsigned array fall outside of the range for English alphabetic characters and numbers, which is why you end up with a string, something like this "3�w��~�H0��-c�" depending on the charset you choose.

For reference:

| Charset | Result |
| --- | --- |
| Charsets.US_ASCII | 3�w��~�H0��-c� |
| Charsets.UTF_8 | 3�w��~�H0��-c� |
| Charsets.UTF_16 | ㏖瞫쁾ᙿ롈ゾ掉 |
| Charsets.UTF_32 | ���� |
| Charsets.ISO_8859_1 | 3Öw«À~¸H0¾î-c |

So, it really depends on *exactly* which encoding the array is using, and *exactly* what it is you're expecting the resulting string to be.

You can play with the code above, [here](https://pl.kotl.in/8Pz1cG4Fn).